# Graph colouring algorithm: typical scheduling problem

Tags: java, c++, algorithm, graph

I'm training code problems like UvA and I have this one in which I *have to, given a set of **n** exams and **k** students enrolled in the exams, find whether it is possible to schedule all exams in **two** time slots*.

**Input**
*Several test cases. Each one starts with a line containing **1 < n < 200** of different examinations to be scheduled. 
The 2nd line has the number of cases **k** in which there exist at least 1 student enrolled in 2 examinations. Then, **k** lines will follow, each containing 2 numbers that specify the pair of examinations for each case above. 
(An input with n = 0 will means end of the input and is not to be processed).*

**Output:**
*You have to decide whether the examination plan is **possible or not** for 2 time slots.*

Example:

Input:

```
3
3
0 1
1 2
2 0
9
8
0 1
0 2
0 3
0 4
0 5
0 6
0 7
0 8
0
```

Ouput:

```
NOT POSSIBLE.
POSSIBLE.
```

I think the general approach is graph colouring, but I'm really a newb and I may confess that I had some trouble understanding the problem.
Anyway, I'm trying to do it and then submit it. 
Could someone please help me doing some code for this problem?
I will have to handle and understand this algo now in order to use it later, over and over.

I prefer C or C++, but if you want, Java is fine to me ;)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've translated the polygenelubricant's pseudocode to JAVA code, in order to provide a solution for my problem. We have a submission platform (like uva/ACM contests), so I know it passed even in the problem with more and hardest cases.

Here it is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author newba
 */
public class GraphProblem {

    class Edge {
        int v1;
        int v2;

        public Edge(int v1, int v2) {
            this.v1 = v1;
            this.v2 = v2;
        }
    }

    public GraphProblem () {
        Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (cin.hasNext()) {

            int num_exams = cin.nextInt();
            if (num_exams == 0)
                break;
            int k = cin.nextInt();
            Hashtable<Integer,String> exams = new Hashtable<Integer, String>();
            ArrayList<Edge> edges = new ArrayList<Edge>();
            for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
                int v1 = cin.nextInt();
                int v2 = cin.nextInt();
                exams.put(v1,"UNKNOWN");
                exams.put(v2,"UNKNOWN");
                //add the edge from A->B and B->A
                edges.add(new Edge(v1, v2));
                edges.add(new Edge(v2, v1));
            }

            boolean possible = true;
            for (Integer key: exams.keySet()){
                if (exams.get(key).equals("UNKNOWN")){
                    if (!colorify(edges, exams,key, "BLACK", "WHITE")){
                        possible = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (possible)
                System.out.println("POSSIBLE.");
            else
                System.out.println("NOT POSSIBLE.");

        }
    }

    public boolean colorify (ArrayList<Edge> edges,Hashtable<Integer,String> verticesHash,Integer node, String color1, String color2){

        verticesHash.put(node,color1);
        for (Edge edge : edges){
            if (edge.v1 == (int) node) {
                if (verticesHash.get(edge.v2).equals(color1)){
                    return false;
                }
                if (verticesHash.get(edge.v2).equals("UNKNOWN")){
                    colorify(edges, verticesHash, edge.v2, color2, color1);
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GraphProblem();
    }
}
```

I didn't optimized yet, I don't have the time right new, but if you want, you/we can discuss it here.

Hope you enjoy it! ;)

Comment: Is `colorify` even a word? =) I just sort of made it up on the spot =) Good job on implementing it and getting it to pass! I like contest-type algorithm problems.

Comment: -1: It's a bad practice to answer your own question (you can just as easily edit the main question or post comments). More so, it's demotivating to others when you accept your own answers based on their posts.

Comment: @pnt That is incorrect. It's an accepted practice to answer your own question. It always has been.

Answer (score 10):

You are correct that this is a graph coloring problem. Specifically, you need to determine if the graph is 2-colorable. This is trivial: do a DFS on the graph, coloring alternating black and white nodes. If you find a conflict, then the graph is not 2-colorable, and the scheduling is impossible.

```
possible = true

for all vertex V
  color[V] = UNKNOWN

for all vertex V
  if color[V] == UNKNOWN
    colorify(V, BLACK, WHITE)

procedure colorify(V, C1, C2)
  color[V] = C1
  for all edge (V, V2)
    if color[V2] == C1
      possible = false
    if color[V2] == UNKNOWN
      colorify(V2, C2, C1)
```

This runs in `O(|V| + |E|)` with adjacency list.

Answer (score 2):

in practice the question is if you can partition the n examinations into two subsets A and B (two timeslots) such that for every pair  in the list of k examination pairs, either a belongs to A and b belongs to B, or a belongs to B and b belongs to A.

You are right that it is a 2-coloring problem; it's a graph with n vertices and there's an undirected arc between vertices a and b iff the pair  or  appears in the list. Then the question is about the graph's 2-colorability, the two colors denoting the partition to timeslots A and B.

A 2-colorable graph is a "bipartite graph". You can test for bipartiteness easily, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph.