# Graph coloring Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, colors, graph

From wiki  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring

> In its simplest form, it is a way of
>   coloring the vertices of a graph such
>   that no two adjacent vertices share
>   the same color; this is called a
>   vertex coloring. Similarly, an edge
>   coloring assigns a color to each edge
>   so that no two adjacent edges share
>   the same color, and a face coloring of
>   a planar graph assigns a color to each
>   face or region so that no two faces
>   that share a boundary have the same
>   color.

**Given 'n' colors and 'm' vertices, how easily can a graph coloring
algorithm be implemented in a programming language?**

Language no barrier.

Just a brain teaser.

(Assume Graph and vertex objects exist)

Edit:
After reading wiki , the problem is **NP-complete**
Time to revisit maths books :)
***my bad.

sorry.***

Just curious,
Has this been tried ? as in writing programs for same?
I heard that this is used in optical networks?

Isn't this similar to cube coloring??
(minimum number of colors to color faces of cube so that no two sides share the same color?)

Comment: Do you want to minimize the number or colors? If you need face coloring then the information on the graph itself does not suffice.

Comment: yes minimizing number of colors .

Comment: If you need pseudo-code in java. Please check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9020742/6-color-graph-vertex-coloring-algorithm

Answer (score 9):

It's an NP complete problem, read the [Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_Colouring#Algorithms) for more information on various methods of solving.

Comment: ahh..my bad .. 
should have attended math classes more often :) or at least read "wiki" better.

Comment: Actually, vertex coloring and edge coloring are two problems. Vertex-coloring is NP complete if you fix the number of colors and is NP-hard if you want to minimize the number of colors.

Comment: @ Tomaž Pisanski you are correct - I assumed vertex colouring and he does say "Given 'n' colours and 'm' vertices, " which to me means fixed colours for a given trial

Answer (score 4):

If you are given 2 colors, and the graph is 2-colorable (i.e. it's a [bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph)), then you can do it in polynomial time quite trivially.

I gave a pseudocode as answer to this question: [Graph colouring algorithm: typical scheduling problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2394098/graph-colouring-algorithm-typical-scheduling-problem).

Answer (score 2):

In my Master's Thesis I testing coloring algorithms. The simplest algorithm is *Edge Backtrace*.

This is my implementation in [Java](https://www.java.com/en/):

```
public boolean edgeBackTrace (List<Edge<T>> edgesList, Map<Edge<T>, List<Edge<T>>> neighborEdges) {
  for (Edge<T> e : edgesList) {
    e.setColor(0);
  }
  int i = 0;
  while (true){
    Edge<T> edge = edgesList.get(i);
    edge.setColor(edge.getColor() + 1);
    if (edge.getColor().equals(4)) {
      edge.setColor(0);
      if (i == 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        i--;
      }
    } else {
      boolean diferentColor = false;

      for (Edge<T> e : neighborEdges.get(edge)) {
        if (e.getColor().equals(edge.getColor())) {
          diferentColor = true;
        }
      }

      if (diferentColor == false) {
        i++;
        if (i == edgesList.size()) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The algorithm returns a value of true if the graph has coloring. You can see in *edgesList* as the color, the individual edges.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, the general problem is np-complete. Bipartite graphs can be colored using only 2 colors.

It is also true that planar graphs (graphs that do not contain [K3,3 or K5](http://www.leda-tutorial.org/en/unofficial/Pictures/NonPlanarGraphs.png) as sub graphs, as per Kuratowski's theorem) can be colored with 4 colors.

Comment: I thought that was map coloring that you can paint every map with at most 4 colors.

Comment: @user177883 Yes, a map is technically a planar graph :)