# 6 Color Graph Vertex Coloring Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

I'm trying to make an algorithm in C++ that will color the vertices of a planar graph with at most 6 colors.  I was just looking for some pseudo code how to go about this to help me get started.  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @EdHeal I thought we stopped tagging homework?  Sure sounds like it though.

Comment: Yes it is.  I know to use a doubly linked list and I think I should designate the first vertex of the non-vacuous j degree list of smallest j as vertex ui. Delete ui from the j degree list. For each vertex U’ that was adjacent to ui in G and remains in some degree list, say j’, delete - u’ from the j’ degree list and insert u’ in the j’ - 1 degree list.  Have a for loop to assign each vertex the smallest color value (between 1-6) not occurring on the vertices adjacent to vi that have already been colored.  How does that sound?

Comment: Sounds like you have seen an extract of the same paper I linked below. The algorithm is fine... so what's the problem? (I recently coded this algorithm in Java, so can give pointers if you are more specific).

Answer (score 6):

See:

*TWO LINEAR-TIME ALGORITHMS FOR FIVE-COLORING A PLANAR GRAPH
by David Matula, Yossi Shiloach, Robert Tarjan*

(Just Google this and you'll find a PDF of the paper).

So this is a paper on 5-coloring a planar graph in O(n) time, but it starts with a simple description on an algorithm for 6-coloring. Here's the important extract (apologies for the formatting, this is just a PDF scrape):

> ALGORITHM 6 COLOR. Given an n vertex planar graph G in adjacency list
>   form, this algorithm determines a 6-coloring of G. Step 1. [Establish
>   degree lists.] For each j where 0- j - n - 1, form a doubly < < linked
>   list of all vertices of G of degree j.
>   - Step 2. [Label vertices smallest degree last.] For i = n, n - 1, n*- 1,. . . , 1 designate the first vertex of the non-vacuous j degree
>   list of smallest j as vertex t/i. Delete vi from the j degree list.
>   For each vertex U’ that was adjacent to tli in G and remains in some
>   degree list, say f, delete u’ from the jr degree list and insert u’ in
>   the j9 - 1 degree list. Step 3. [Color vertices.] For i = 1,2,. . . ,
>   n, assign vertex t)i the smallest color value (which must be some
>   integer between one and six) not occuring on the vertices adjacent to
>   t)i that have already been colored.