# How to group and merge objects, if some are incompatible with each other?

Tags: algorithm, graph, grouping

I have a bunch of objects, which I want to merge into as few composite objects as possible.

I can calculate whether any 2 objects can or cannot be merged, and if they can be merged, merge them.

An object A is incompatible with another B made of N merged objects if and only if A is incompatible with one or more elements of B.

The greedy solution (merge into first which works) fails for 4 objects, where 1x4 (1 can't be grouped with 4), 2x3, 3x4. The greedy solution puts objects 1 and 2 into group 1, then object 3 into group 2, and object 4 into group 3. The correct solution is putting objects 1 and 3 into group 1, and objects 2 and 4 into group 2.

What is the name of the problem, and is it solvable? If so, what's the algorithm?

(Worst case = brute force, which is slow but workable, because I am merging very small numbers of objects.)

Edit: Merging fails if cannot be merged, otherwise merges. Both unmerged and merged are accessible. Takes O(size(a) + size(b)) time and returns an object of size (a+b). Assume size is around 1000.

Comment: This could be modeled as graph vertex coloring problem. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2445380/718379

Comment: https://youtu.be/c1UBJbfR-H0?t=1574

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this as a graph problem. Every object is a vertex, and there is an edge `(v1, v2)` if and only if `v1` and `v2` are compatible. You are now looking for a [clique cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover_problem), which is NP-complete.

Note that the clique cover is a decision problem (is it possible to cover the graph with `k` cliques?), but you can turn this into an optimization problem by doing a binary search for `k` (can I cover with, say, 8 cliques? If yes, try 4, if no, try 16, etc). The problem is still NP-complete then.

---

As @timrau already commented - and as mentioned in the wikipedia link - the complement problem is [graph coloring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring): you have the same vertices, but now there is an edge `(v1, v2)` if and only if `v1` and `v2` are *incompatible*. You then want to find the minimum number of colors needed to color your vertices, such that no adjacent vertices have the same color. Wikipedia also provides a number of [algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Algorithms) for that.