# Find number of groups, that can be formed from two lists

Tags: python, algorithm

Goal of task is to group animals, so the enemies not in the same cage.
There are m pairs (a[i],b[i]) which imply that animals a[i] and b[i] are enemies and should not be kept in one cage.

Given n=3 animals and m=3 pairs of enemies, a=[1,2,3] and b=[3,3,1]
Animal 1 is enemy of animal 3 and 3 is enemy of 1 and 3. There four are possible groupings {1,2},{1},{2},{3}. Note that the intervals are along  the original line of animals numbered from 1 to n i.e [1,2,3]. They can't be reordered or skipped. So grouping {2,1} and {1,3} will be wrong.

I've used just hash map to map out all enemies and go through all animals, but it's not effective.

```py
a = [1,2]  # group a
b = [3,5]  # group b


n = 5  # number of animals 

def groupAnimals(n,a,b):
    h = {}
    groups = []
    for index, animal in enumerate(a):
        h[animal] = b[index]
        h[b[index]] = a[index]

    for i in range(1,n+1):
        groups.append([i])
        curr = [i]
        for j in range(i+1,n+1):
            if j - curr[-1] > 1:
                break 
            if j in h:
                if h[j] not in curr:
                    curr = curr.copy()
                    curr.append(j)
                    groups.append(curr)
            else:
                curr = curr.copy()
                curr.append(j)
                groups.append(curr)

    return len(groups)
```

The result of above code is correct, but some test cases are failed.
How to improve the code? Is there better solution?

Comment: So we have a=[1,2,3] and b=[3,3,1]. In this case animal 1 is enemy of animal 3 and animal 3 is enemy of 1 and 2

Comment: I think this is related to finding the minimum number of [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)) covering a graph if you start with a fully-connected graph and remove edges for each pair of "enemies". This is called the "clique cover number". Maybe this helps you find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues in your code:

1. What if an animal has more than one enemy? The value of the enemy is overwritten. Try with `a = [3,3]` and `b = [1,5]`: `h[1] = 3` and `h[3] = 5`, hence `1` and `3` may be in the same cage but they are enemies;
2. you are building only a part of the powerset of `1..N` because you never skip a `j`: you build `[1], [1,2], [1,2,3], ...`, then `[2], [2,3], ...` but never `[1,3]`. Proof: try with `a=[]`, `b=[]` and `n=5`. You should get `2^5-1` = 31
3. I don't understand the meaning of

   ```
   if j - curr[-1] > 1:
       break
   ```

   It removes acceptable groups, like `[1, 2, 4]` in your example.

To address the first issue, you have to store the group of enemies (maybe void) for each animal. BTW, instead of playing with indices (`enumerate`), you can zip `a` and `b` to get the enemies by pairs:

```
def compute_enemies(N, a, b):
    enemies = {}
    for animal, other in zip(a, b):
        enemies.setdefault(animal, set()).add(other)
        enemies.setdefault(other, set()).add(animal)
    return enemies
```

The `setdefault` get the set mapped to the key or create a new empty set.

```
>>> compute_enemies(5, [3, 3], [1 ,5])
{3: {1, 5}, 1: {3}, 5: {3}}
```

To adress the second issue, you have to compute all subsets of a `range(1, N+1)`. That's the [powerset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of this range. Here's a recursive definition:

- `PS([1, ..., N]) = PS([1, ..., N-1]) u {S u {N} for all S in PS([1, ..., N-1])}` (all the previous sets, and the same + element `{N}`)
- `PS([]) = {}`

In python:

```
def powerset(N):
    if N == 0:
        yield set()
    else:
        for s in powerset(N-1):
            yield s
            yield s | {N}

>>> list(powerset(3))
[set(), {3}, {2}, {2, 3}, {1}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 3}]
```

Note: including the empty set and the range itself, you have `2^N` subsets. The keyword `yield` creates a generator (`yield` has also a role in co-routines, but that's another story), hence the `list(...)` to collect the elements.

Now, we have to adapt this function to add the enemy parameter. We check if `N` is an enemy before yielding `s | {N}`:

```
def group_animals_aux(N, enemies):
    if N == 0:
        yield set()
    else:
        for s in group_animals_aux(N-1, enemies):
            yield s
            if N not in set(y for x in s for y in enemies.get(x, set())): # union of all sets of enemies
                yield s | {N}
```

Some details on `set(y for x in s for y in enemies.get(x, set()))`: 1) `enemies.get(x, set())` returns either the enemies of x, or an empty set. 2) `set(y for x in s for y in ...)` takes all elements of `s` (one of the subsets) (`for x in s`), then all enemies of this element, and build a new set with all the enemies. Bascially, it perfoms a union of all enemies of animals in the set.

To avoid to repeat this computation, we can carry the enemies of the group along with the group:

```
def group_animals_aux2(N, enemies):
    if N == 0:
        yield set(), set()
    else:
        for s, e in group_animals_aux2(N-1, enemies):
          yield s, e # s: animals, e: union of all enemies
            if N not in e:
                # add N to the animals, and its enemies to the enemies of the group
                yield s | {N}, e | enemies.get(N, set()) 

>>> enemies = compute_enemies(5, [3, 3], [1 ,5])
>>> [s for s, _ in group_animals_aux2(5, enemies)]
[set(), {5}, {4}, {4, 5}, {3}, {3, 4}, {2}, {2, 5}, {2, 4}, {2, 4, 5}, {2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {1}, {1, 5}, {1, 4}, {1, 4, 5}, {1, 2}, {1, 2, 5}, {1, 2, 4}, {1, 2, 4, 5}]
```

Let's put the parts together:

```
def group_animals(N, a, b):
    enemies = compute_enemies(N, a, b)
    return len(list(group_animals_aux2(N, enemies))) - 1 # remove the empty cage 

>>> group_animals(5, [3, 3], [1 ,5])
19
```

*Remark 1:* given the complexiy of the algorithm `O(2^N)` I hope that you don't have too many animals, or that these animals have a lot of enemies.

*Remark 2:* if you were looking for the minimum number of cages to lock your animals, you should consider @tobias_k comment: this is would be the [clique cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_cover) problem, more precisely a [graph coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring) problem. See this question and the answer for more information: [How to group and merge objects, if some are incompatible with each other?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27814586/how-to-group-and-merge-objects-if-some-are-incompatible-with-each-other/27814722#27814722).

Comment: Thank you for such deep answer. I will also follow up with graph solution